# Flag intentional http request cancellation of api requests with same url

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

This is http interceptor service that should handle cancellation of previous requests with the same url. I have a problem with handling rejection after calling 'resolve' method which falls into a 'catch' handler of my angular data service.
How to flag this cancellation as intentional, so my data service does not indicate that an error occurred on server side? I don't want to display error message in this case.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('common')
    .factory('abortService', abortService);

abortService.$inject = ['$q', '$filter'];

function abortService($q, $filter) {

    var service = {
        request: request,
        };
    var error = "";
    var currentRequests = [];

    return service;


    function request(request) {

        if (!request.url.includes('api/')) return request;

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        request.timeout = deferred.promise;

        var existingRequests = $filter('filter')(currentRequests, { url: request.url }, true);
        existingRequests.forEach(function (request) {
            request.promiseObj.resolve('intentional_reject');//how to flag as intentional reject??
        });

        currentRequests.push({ url: request.url, promiseObj: deferred });

        return request;
    }

};})();
```

And here is my angular data service method:

```
function getBalanceDueSummary(businessPartnerCode) {
        return $http({
            method: "get",
            url: "/api/BusinessPartnerAPI/GetBalanceDueSummary",
            params:
                {
                    businessPartnerCode: businessPartnerCode,
                }
        })
        .then(complete)
        .catch(failed);

        function complete(response) {
            return response.data;
        }

        function failed(error) { //here my cancellation falls into, but i have no data which indicates intentional cancellation
            //logService.exception displays a toastr message when error occurrs
            logService.exception(error, 'GetBalanceDueSummary');
            return $q.reject(error);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this using a custom Status Code for the cancelling? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29356962/angular-js-set-http-status-code-for-cancelled-requests

Comment: I tried that now. Custom status code could not be accepted, I always get -1 for status.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some digging and found the value 'intentional_reject' in object:
error.Config.timeout.$$state.value

```
function getBalanceDueSummary(businessPartnerCode) {
        return $http({
            method: "get",
            url: "/api/BusinessPartnerAPI/GetBalanceDueSummary",
            params:
                {
                    businessPartnerCode: businessPartnerCode,
                }
        })
        .then(complete)
        .catch(failed);

        function complete(response) {
            return response.data;
        }

        function failed(error) {
            if(!(error.Config.timeout.$$state.value &&
                error.Config.timeout.$$state.value=='intentional_reject'))
                    logService.exception(error, 'GetBalanceDueSummary');
            return $q.reject(error);
        }
    }
```

I doubt this is the best solution for this but I could not set response status manually...